# DC Power Schematic Feedback (Review)

Tags: power-supply, filter

Below is the schematic of the DC power circuit of a project I'm working on. I'd like to get some feedback on whether I should make any changes/improvements.

The input is from a switching wall-wart at 15VDC, polarity irrelevant.

[image]

Specifically, I have 3 questions:

1. The bidrectional TVS differential diode is used for surge protection, the unidirectional diodes to chassis ground are for ESD. Is this reasonable, and have I wired them in correctly?
2. Would it be better to place the differential LC L-Filter (L1-C1) before the rectifier and after the CM-choke, then add a second inductor in the com-line, or would this not make a significant difference? The initial benefit I saw of doing it as in the schematic is only one inductor is required, but maybe filtering would be better the other way.
3. Any other changes/improvements I should make?

Chassis is earth grounded directly with a cable.

**Additional Info:** This is an audio device used in an FM environment, powered by a CUI SWI6-15-N 15V switching wall-wart @ 25-30kHz. The regulator output is 12V. The circuitry is all analog, no microcontroller. Supply current is around 190mA max for under a minute at a time, otherwise around 30mA.  The choke is a wurth 744235110 (11uH)  was chosen with the caps to filter RF in the FM range specifically, with a minimum around 100MHz from what I simulated (ESL = 1.1nF, ESR 0.23Ohm). The ESD unidirectional TVS's are 400W calculated using human body model, handling an 8kV (330 Ohm source) discharge from VCC or COM over max 100ns. The bidirectional TVS diode is 1500W in case the are any line surges.

Comment: Without understanding your design aims, it's impossible to say if the circuit meets them.

Comment: What information do you need? Not expecting anyone to verify filter attenuation, calculations, etc. But I don't have enough experience to know if the topology is reasonable. Was hoping some EE would be able to point out anything that is glaringly unorthodox or isn't going to work as effectively as it would if the circuit were arranged differently, regardless of the numbers.

Comment: Just put yourself in a readers position and ask yourself what is the bare essential information needed to justify your choice of certain parts.

Comment: Clearly if I knew the answer to that question, I wouldn't have asked "what information do you need?" I didn't ask for anyone to verify if my parts are correct. I asked mainly two things, are my TVS diodes wired up correctly assuming human body (or any other) ESD discharge at the connector or a surge voltage coming in from behind the wall somewhere, and is it generally better to do all filtering before the rectifier in a situation like this (where rectifier is used only for polarity with DC input) or it fine post rectifier.

Comment: And is there anything glaringly unorthodox with the schematic layout, where someone experienced would say, "oh wait, if you have a ESD discharge then this or that component might be damaged, swap these parts around, or add this or that component to protect them.", for example.

Comment: OK, why did you choose a linear regulator and what parameters were important in that choice?

Comment: This is an audio device, so I wanted to keep as much switching noise out of the system as possible, since it's already being powered by a switching wall-wart (switching freq around 30kHz). The regulator output is 12V. The circuitry is all analog, no microcontroller or anything.  Important parameters were that it was an LDO so I could get 12V, from as minimal a supply voltage as possible, and that it was relatively low noise (I compared noise figures of different regulators and this seemed to be the best, although I didn't have hard numbers I was looking to achieve).

Comment: So, output current didn't strike you as important?

Comment: It also needed to be able to supply around 220mA, and this regulator could also handle load-dump type surges and reverse polarity (although both aren't entirely necessary in this application), and had a high input voltage capability.  And it was small and compact, and didn't need to dissipate a lot of heat as an LDO.

Comment: So why didn't you write that in the question in the first place - people aren't falling over to answer this because they recognize that to extract the data from you will take up too much of their valuable time. Nobody gets paid for answering. Also, without knowledge of the wall-wart it's impossible to decide why you hung 3 TVS diodes at the power input and what motivated you to use the unspecified common-mode choke.

Comment: Had i posted all of the info you just requested, I would have gotten another response from someone else saying, "narrow your question, I couldn't be bothered to read your entire text, and that information is irrelevant." There seems to be an obsession on this board with HOW people ask questions, we could have condensed the above 7 responses and the discussion of this had you just said, "to answer that I need to know XYZ". I'm not an EE, nor are many on this board judging by many of the questions. Sometimes I don't know what information is relevant, and I can't read your mind to know what...

Comment: you feel is relevant specifically. Andy I have read a number of your responses, and whenever I see your name and it's a detailed response, I know it's going to be a worthwhile read and I'm going to learn something. But I've noticed that a lot of your responses are like this, and you're right, it is time wasted. You clearly have lots of knowledge and experience, and everyone benefits from your responses. But by not assuming that everyone is as experienced as you, we could save that wasted time and discussion and get to answering the actual questions.

Comment: Well I'm sorry you feel that way but your profile gives no indication as to how competent you are so I am at an immediate disadvantage so I ask questions to get a feel for your competency. I ask those sort of questions to see if I can afford to spend time getting to the bottom of things. I also check previous questions you have asked and clearly you don't appear to understand answers given or your accept-rate would be a bit more.

Comment: With regard to the wall-wart, it's a CUI SWI6-15-N. The choke is a wurth 744235110 was chosen with the caps to filter RF in the FM range specifically, with a minimum around 100MHz from what I simulated. The bidirectional TVS diode I added because I was told by a former EE coworker, that I should add a 1500W TVS diode there in case the are any line surges. The ESD unidirectional TVS's I calculated using human body model, according to the charts they seemed to be able to handle the power of an 8kV discharge over max 100ns easily

Comment: Ok in that case let me state that I don't have an electronics background (engineering, yes) and only started experimenting with designing electronics as a hobbyist about 6 months ago, and am hoping to maybe do it professionally at some point. I will update this in my profile to reflect this. Where in the circuit I placed the filters and the way I drew the schematic was based on my understanding of how they should work, and it certainly works fine. But whether the order of the components is optimal or not I don't have enough experience to say.

Comment: Profile updated. W/ regard to the answer-rate, I always up-vote comments that are helpful but only mark something as an answer if I read it and feel it truly answered my question, not just vaguely /or clearly pointed in the right direction. Now that we've gotten all of the non-relevant commentary out of the way... any other specifics you need to know to answer the above questions? Or can you at least give me your thoughts on the circuit schematic?

Comment: @DiBosco, the bridge rectifier is there to allow a DC power supply with either polarity (center + or center -) at the input.

Comment: "I wanted to keep as much switching noise out of the system as **possible**" - then you have failed, because you could have designed a circuit which 'keeps out' more noise than this one.

Comment: @BruceAbbott - could you contribute something constructive instead? Like maybe suggest a better filter topology? Or explain in a few sentences how I might go about determining how much noise and in what frequency range I should be trying to attenuate coming from the supply given the information you've read in the question and comments?

Comment: What is the heat sink thermal resistance?

Comment: There is no heat sink. Standard operating current is around 25mA, and measured regulator drop was around 1.7V, so 42.5mW.  Just recalculated, high current is around 190mA only for short periods of about 30-45 seconds once a week, and that gives a reg drop of about 0.6-0.7V, soldered to the board even when on for prolonged periods the regulator doesn't even really get warm to the touch.

Comment: If the input voltage is 24 volts then the dissipated power in the regulator is over two watts.

Comment: @Andy Good point, I've been testing on 15V the entire time as the wall-wart is 15V and was planning for the case where someone uses a different supply, thought I accounted for that but it's looking like I didn't, will have to go back and check my notes. I sized the components to handle that situation but looks like I didn't consider regulator dissipation at the upper voltage limit

Comment: This is exactly why we discourage broad, open-ended design review questions here on EE.SE: The answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow design review questions in which you explain your choices and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts. To get a better feel of what is or is not acceptable, search for "design review" on the meta site.

Comment: @DaveTweed to be fair, if you removed the non-question-related comments above, it would reduce to only a few comments. But fair enough, I'll have a look at the meta.

Comment: @Andyaka - ok, checked my notes, the option of using a +24V supply was based on a previous design iteration, this version was only intended for 15V and the regulator dissipation was the reason why. Good catch, original post updated, need to update that in the schematic.  I have other specific questions about the TVS selection, but will just ask these in separate, simplified posts.

Comment: Update your question with all the relevant facts uncovered then @DaveTweed can do the correct thing and delete all this flotsam.

Comment: "suggest a better filter topology? Or ... how much noise and in what frequency range I should be trying to attenuate coming from the supply given the information you've read in the question and comments?" - there is no noise specification in the question and I shouldn't have to tease it out of the comments. At first glance your design seem grossly over-engineered, but without knowing how much noise is acceptable it's impossible to say whether the topology is appropriate.

Comment: @BruceAbbott - From my response: "Or explain in a few sentences how I might go about determining how much noise and in what frequency range I should be trying to attenuate coming from the supply given the information you've read?" - This would say to me that the person who asked it isn't exactly sure how to determine what noise specs he/she should be aiming for. Assuming it's a pro-audio device in a high RF(mainly FM)environment, maybe you could provide guidance there. "At first glance your design seem grossly over-engineered"-that's the kind of answer I appreciate, but with a bit more detail.

Comment: @Andyaka agreed, will update the question with relevant info as soon as I have some extra time so the irrelevant comments can all be deleted